# Remove empty lines from a preformatted CSV

Tags: excel, vba, csv, batch-file, filter

im generating a CSV from an XLS file with VBA, after that I am filtering the CSV with Batch. My filter looks like this:

```
for %%a in (*.csv) do (

  for /f "usebackq tokens=1-10 delims=, eol=^" %%1 in ("%%a") do (
    if %%4 EQU Req_Category ECHO %%1,%%2,%%3,%%4,%%5,%%6,%%7,%%8,%%9 >> "%%a"_JIRA.csv
    if %%4 EQU Requirement ECHO %%1,%%2,%%3,%%4,%%5,%%6,%%7,%%8,%%9 >> "%%a"_JIRA.csv
  )

)
```

This works fine if the CSV File has no empty lines.
In rare occasions the XLS -> CSV converting generates empty lines or CRs in the CSV.

```
SW_Fn-289,4.1.1.1,Controling Hardware PCB,Heading,,,,,IgnoreTesting,
SW_Fn-291,4.1.1.1.0-1," 
Date : 07.03.1777

The SystemDesignSpecification is stored in SVN path
http://sblablablabla.xlsm
",Requirement,Lab1 (B-Sample),,Released,Accepted,IgnoreTesting,
SW_Fn-4281,4.1.1.1.0-2," 
Date : 123.123.123

Path : https://apath.com
",Requirement,R1,,New,New,IgnoreTesting,
SW_Fn-166,4.2,Compliance Requirements,Heading,,,,,IgnoreTesting,
SW_Fn-286,4.2.1,Resource Usage,Heading,,,,,IgnoreTesting,
```

Every line in the CSV should start with an ID: SW_Fn-Example.
Does every one have an idea how can bring the info on one line with a batch function?

I need to get the file to look like this (before filtering):

```
SW_Fn-289,4.1.1.1,Controling Hardware PCB,Heading,,,,,IgnoreTesting,
SW_Fn-291,4.1.1.1.0-1,"Date : 07.03.1777 TheSystemDesignSpecificationisstored in SVN path http://sblablablabla.xlsm",Requirement,Lab1 (B-Sample),,Released,Accepted,IgnoreTesting,
SW_Fn-4281,4.1.1.1.0-2," Date : 123.123.123 Path : https://apath.com",Requirement,R1,,New,New,IgnoreTesting,
SW_Fn-166,4.2,Compliance Requirements,Heading,,,,,IgnoreTesting,
SW_Fn-286,4.2.1,Resource Usage,Heading,,,,,IgnoreTesting,
```

There shouldnt be a line that does not start with SW_Fn-blabla. If a line starts with something else, then it should be a part of the previous line that has an Sw_Fn-blabla.

Then my filter will work to produce this:

```
SW_Fn-291,4.1.1.1.0-1,"Date : 07.03.1777 TheSystemDesignSpecificationisstored in SVN path http://sblablablabla.xlsm",Requirement,Lab1 (B-Sample),,Released,Accepted,IgnoreTesting,
SW_Fn-4281,4.1.1.1.0-2," Date : 123.123.123 Path : https://apath.com",Requirement,R1,,New,New,IgnoreTesting,
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Three of the five lines in your desired output shouldn't be there according to your filter. ?

Comment: I've edited it. Just kinda tired today. The filter works fine if the info is on one line. I have problems achieving my goal if the information is splitted Thanks

Comment: if your conversion is unreliable, you probably should rather fix that instead of doing postprocessing on data with unreliable formatting.

Comment: @Stephan - Actually the file is a valid CSV format. CSV allows for newlines in quoted fields, though many naive readers do not support it.

Answer (score 0):

Aak! don't use numerics for the `metavariable` (`%%1`) - it's highly unreliable. Use an alphabetic character.

Batch treats a string of delimiters as a single delimiter and you have nominated commas and spaces as delimiters, so

```
SW_Fn-166,4.2,Compliance Requirements,Heading,,,,,IgnoreTesting,
```

would appear as

```
SW_Fn-166,4.2,Compliance,Requirements,Heading,IgnoreTesting,,,,
```

You haven't shown what you expect as output. Do you only want the lines that begin `SW_Fn-` or do you want all lines that don't start `SW-Fn` appended to the last line that did?

---

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36475816.csv"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "line="
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "newpart=%%a"
 IF DEFINED line CALL :test
 IF DEFINED line CALL SET "line=%%line%% %%a"
 IF NOT DEFINED line SET "line=%%a"
)
IF DEFINED line ECHO(%line%
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:: Test new data " Accumulate data into line or output & start a new line
:test
SET "newpart=%newpart:"=x%"
IF NOT "%newpart:~0,6%"=="SW_Fn-" goto :eof
echo(%line%
SET "line="
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36475816.csv` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Note that your posted data contains unbalanced quotes in the `Fn-4281` item. It's always better to use actual data rather than "somewhere close".

Read each line. If we've already accumulated part of a line, check whether the first few characters are the target. If they are, output the line as constructed and clear `line`.

If `line` is clear after this operation, set it to the line read (which must startwith the target, otherwise accumulate the line.

In the `:test` procedure, remove quotes before testing so that it doesn't break the syntax. Obviously, if the first few characters contains a quote, it doesn't fit the target so the test will correctly detect `"no fit"`

Comment: Hi, i would like to get all the lines that dont start with `Sw_Fn-` appended to the last line that did. Thank you for your tipp on the numerics and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.csv) do (
  for /f "delims=" %%b in (%%a) do (
    for /f "tokens=4 delims=," %%c in ("%%b") do (
      if "%%c"=="Requirement" echo %%b >>%%~na_JIRA%%~xa
      if "%%c"=="Req_Category" echo %%b >>%%~na_JIRA%%~xa
    )
  )
)
```

read and handle each line complete to overcome the consecutive-delimiter-issue mentioned by Magoo (use another `for` to check Token4, but don't bother to disassemble and reassemble the complete line)

Answer (score 0):

Your file is actually valid CSV format. Quoted CSV fields may contain any of the following:

- comma
- quote literal, escaped as `""`
- newline (either LF or CRLF)

You don't have commas or quotes within your fields, but you do have newlines that are giving your code serious problems.

But that is only one potential problem. Another issue is FOR /F treats consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter, so if any of your desired keeper lines have any empty fields, then your output will be completely wrong.

Batch is inherently far from ideal for any kind of text processing, but for CSV it is especially bad for all but the most simplest problems. If you really want to use batch, you could use [ParseCSV.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5702) to properly parse your CSV and read it using FOR /F in a reliable manner. But there are better options.

PowerShell has an `Import-Csv` cmdlet. I'm not sure of its capabilities, but if it supports newlines within fields, then you could develop a really slick solution with that.

Another option is my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processor](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). The following code looks nasty, but it will very efficiently produce your desired output in one step:

```
jrepl "((?:[\s\S]*?,){3}(?:(Req_Category,|Requirement,)|.*?,)(?:.*?,){4}.*?),[^,\n]*\n?" "$2?$1.replace(/\r\n/g,' ')+'\r\n':''" /m /j /f input.csv /o output.csv
```

You would need to use CALL JREPL if you put the command within another batch script.

My JREPL solution relies on the fact that none of your input fields contain quoted commas. If it did contain quoted commas, then a JREPL solution would be even more complicated.

This solution works by using the /M multiline option so that I can match across line-breaks.

The search matches each 10 field collection (your 10th field seems to be always empty), regardless of line breaks. $1 contains the first 9 fields (without the trailing comma). $2 contains the 4th field if and only if it matches "Req_Category" or "Requirement". The replacement javascript expression tests if $2 is defined, and if it is, then the whole search expression is replaced with $1 after all newlines have been replaced by spaces, and then a newline is appended. IF $2 is not defined then the whole search expression is replaced with an empty string. Simple in concept, but kind of nasty to develop ;-)

A slight simplification allows you to preserve the original fields containing newlines, and still do the filtering you desire.:

```
jrepl "((?:[\s\S]*?,){3}(?:(Req_Category,|Requirement,)|.*?,)(?:.*?,){4}.*?),[^,\n]*\n?" "$2?$1+'\r\n':''" /m /j /f input.csv /o output.csv
```